# Ionic: Header Title Bold

Tags: ionic-framework

I have a side menu:

```
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">
    <ion-side-menu-content>
        <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive" align-title="center">
            <ion-nav-back-button>
            </ion-nav-back-button>

            <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
                <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">
                </button>
            </ion-nav-buttons>
        </ion-nav-bar>
        <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-side-menu-content>

    <ion-side-menu side="left" width="300">
        <ion-content>
            <div class="list">
                <a class="item item-icon-left" ui-sref="app.bla" menu-close>
                    <i class="icon menu-icon ion-home"></i>
                    <h2>Bla</h2>
                </a>
                <a class="item item-icon-left" ui-sref="app.blub" menu-close>
                    <i class="icon menu-icon ion-person"></i>
                    <h2>Blub</h2>
                </a>
            </div>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

And i want to modify the title which is set in each view:

```
<ion-view view-title="MyTitle">
    <ion-content>

    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

How can i modify the title like setting it to `bold` or let it left align or right?

Comment: what css properties have you tried ? hadd a codepen

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PqOWEJ

Comment: i dont know which css to use. ion-view, view-title, ion-side-menu, h1, ion-nav-bar all does not work

Comment: ion-nav-view>header {
  background-color:green !important;
}

Comment: im sorry... but.. what? `ion-nav-view>header` i never used `>` in html or css like that. can you explain what that does?

Comment: it checked for tag ion-nav-view and son tag header.

Comment: ok got it. but i still dont get bold to work. `ion-nav-view>header { font-weight: bold !important; }` does not work